# How do I load a javascript file as text (String)?

Tags: lift

I know can load html (`NodeSeq`) by using `Templates("file" :: "address" :: Nil)`.  Is there a similar way to load a JavaScript file from `/src/main/webapp/` as `InputStream` or `String`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution, let it stay in history...

One can obtain resource files from inside `/src/main/webapp/` by using `LiftRules.loadResourceAsString("/index.html").openOr("")`

For example, to load a JS file as `JcCmd` one can use `JsCmds.Run(LiftRules.loadResourceAsString("/js/my.js").openOr(""))`

Comment: Is that a difference between loadResource and loadResourceAsString?

Comment: nafg, ah, damn, I didn't notice that I finally used almost the same method I started with.. So, resources are loaded from many directories, not from one.. I'll edit my initial question so it'll make more sense.